# Accessibility Menu items no longer selectable under OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, finder, menu-bar, accessibility

If I'm not mistaken, in earlier editions of OS X, the menu items pictured below could be selected to turn them on or off.

Apparently, that's changed in Yosemite. Is there a way to turn on each accessibility feature from the contextual menu rather than selecting "Accessibility Preferences" to turn them on and off in System Preferences?

[image]

Comment: Is it enabled in the syst pref Accessibility, Show accessibility status in Menu bar?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I think OP's point is that the options in the menu are all greyed out, whereas in prior versions you could click on them to change their status. Literally all the menu bar option does anymore is show you the status - you still have to open System Preferences from there to make changes.

Comment: @tubedogg is right. Using a contextual menu to display what features are turned on rather than a feature toggle is downright bizarre from a UI perspective.

Answer (score 1):

The menubar item in Yosemite no longer allows you to make direct changes to the settings, it is merely an advisory list of what is on and off.

You can make changes to the settings in the list below, previously accessible from the menubar, by pressing <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> and ticking the appropriate boxes (see screenshot). The remaining settings, and others, can be set in System Preferences.

- Invert screen colors
- Mouse keys
- Sticky keys
- Slow keys
- VoiceOver

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all do option command f5 and press keyboard shortcuts,then select accessibility and tick inverted colors, now whenever you want to have inverted screen just do ctrl option command 8

Hope this helps ya!